# Drop a selection of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm aware of the commands for dropping a single table or all tables. But in this scenario I need to be able to drop a selection of tables in `SQL CE`. I know it is possible to do this logic on the application level but I was wondering if it was possible to do this in a single SQL command? I have been unable to find out an answer to this question elsewhere.

I have previously attempted:

`drop table table1, table2, table3`

But this did not work. Is it possible to do this in a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible in a single statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173418.aspx

Comment: Erik, your SQLCE bulk-copy API is absolutely fantastic. You are a legend!